# pyspark JOB fails with "No space left on device"

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, pyspark

I am on a standalone cluster of Master+3WorkerNodes, When running a job(BIG), I am facing an issue of "No space left on device".

I tried getting help of [Why does a job fail with "No space left on device", but df says otherwise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707784/why-does-a-job-fail-with-no-space-left-on-device-but-df-says-otherwise)  and set the variable in MASTER's spark-defaults.conf

```
spark.local.dir            SOME/DIR/WHERE/YOU/HAVE/SPACE
```

then restarted the cluster. But noticed that after changing that also, it is still pointing to /tmp(saw memory usage while job was running by df -h) for temporary shuffle store instead of pointing to directory I set in defaults.conf(I can see this directory in webUI's environment TAB).

WHY /tmp is still pointed, any IDEA ? do i need to set anything-else-anywhere??

Also followed [Spark：java.io.IOException: No space left on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162845/spark-java-io-ioexception-no-space-left-on-device)  and get:  I need to set below property in spark-evn.sh

```
SPARK_JAVA_OPTS+=" -Dspark.local.dir=/mnt/spark,/mnt2/spark -Dhadoop.tmp.dir=/mnt/ephemeral-hdfs"

export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS
```

What is "/mnt/spark" and "/mnt/ephemeral-hdfs" path denotes??  And do i need to set it on master's spark-env.sh or on every worker-Node also.

Pleas Help. Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, got the solution, I think setting "spark.local.dir" will be overriden by saprk defaults i:e /tmp path.

But setting the below 2 variables in each of master and worker's "spark-env.sh" worked.

```
export SPARK_WORKER_DIR=dir_you_have_enough_Space
export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=dir_you_have_enough_Space
```

Hope it'll help somebody-someday..:)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution.